# Is there any particular reason why the flag counter on my moderator election nomination is different from what the flag counter on my profile says?

Tags: support, flagging, election, moderator-elections

The flag counter on my [moderator nomination](https://superuser.com/election/3#post-744851) states that I have 364 helpful flags (as of the instant this question was posted). However, the counter on my user profile states that I have 535 helpful flags. Why do the counters differ? Are specific types of flags not counted in the one on the election nomination, or is the flag counter there *net* helpful flags (i.e. one is subtracted for each flag that is declined)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You've cast total of 595 flags, out of these 535 flags were acted upon, hence considered "helpful".

From this,

- 75 declined
- 27 disputed
- 33 marked as spam (spam flags are considered separately)
- 36 on comments (comment flags aren't counted)

535 - 75 - 27 - 33 - 36 = 364 flags which were acknowledged as helpful by Moderators

Comment: Ah, so I see. Flags on comments as well as spam flags on posts aren't counted, and then after that the counter counts *net* helpful flags (i.e. helpful-(declined+disputed)).