# Why is Helpful flag count in moderator election different from my profile

Tags: support, flagging, moderator-elections, moderator-nomination

I did happen to find that [Is there any particular reason why the flag counter on my moderator election nomination is different from what the flag counter on my profile says?](https://meta.superuser.com/q/7921/162960) has an answer that states that there would be a difference in helpful flag counts because **comment flags** aren't counted and neither are **spam flags**, as well as the obvious **disputed** and **declined flags** that aren't counted.

My post says 8 helpful flags

and my profile says:

[image: Picture of flagging]

which adds up to 12, if I don't count the offensive post flag that was deemed helpful.

I have the same question

Comment: You have 3 flags dating back to '12, I believe some of the older flags are not counted due to the way the flagging system was changed

Comment: thanks for the edit...lol. I am using a wireless keyboard, and I am not sold on it,  came with the computer and I think it sucks, I don't like the keys and it drops occasionally during typing

Comment: sorry I was off on another tangent there for a minute,  @Sathya if there are only 3 that predate '12 (and don't count) I would be at 9 flags (considering my math is correct